# PHP 5.3.5 With Zend Debugger

Tags: php

I am trying to get the zend debugger to work but till now I have failed. I have searched everywhere and tried everything I found but still not working.

I am using windows 7 64 bit with Zend studio professional edition 8.0. I have vmware installed on windows and have an opensuse 11.4 64 bit server setup. it is installed in minimal so i dont have gui just commands. On open suse i have php 5.3.5, apache 2.2.17 and mysql installed. I also installed Zend Debugger 5.3.X which I downloaded from zend's website. I've put the ZendDebugger.so file into /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/

I inserted the following in the php.ini for debugger

```
[Zend]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/ZendDebugger.so"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts= 127.0.0.1, 192.168.4.70
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

in phpinfo(), zend debugger is not loading

anyone know what I am doing wrongly here or any suggestions i should try?

Thank you

UPDATE!!
Since I have not managed to get this thing working with my setup could anyone of you tell me if I can use XDebug with my setup i.e. Zend studio 8 + Apache + XDebug?

Comment: Regarding XDebug; yes you can

Comment: Yes have used xdebug a lot, no issues in many different similar setups.  There's a fairly recent howto for setup here:  http://www.flingbits.com/tutorial/view/xdebug-for-developing-debugging-and-profiling-php  Thought you might be interested in case you want to give xdebug a look as an alternative.

Comment: XDebug not available for `php` older then `5.5`. It can be checked from theirs website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally after trying everything I found the solution for the problem.

I had a missing file in linux so zend debugger wasnt working. To find what was the problem I used the following command in linux

PHP -m

This shows all the modules that are installed on the OS and if there are any problems it will tell you what the problems are. I got an error message of missing libssl.so 0.9.8. Opened yast -> software management types SSL and installed the 0.9.8 and everything is fine now.

Comment: I had the same problem on Ubuntu 12.  a quick `sudo aptitude install libssl0.9.8` and an apache restart later and it is now working

Answer (score 1):

Zend studio 8 and 9 are not compatible with `xdebug` since the Zend studio team developers do not test that XDebug works in their IDE as we speak. Read more here:

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=24113

My conclusion is that Eclipse Indigo with PDT is the best solution out there for the moment until the Zend developers solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've followed the [instructions](http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Debugger-Installation-Guide.pdf) to the letter with the exception of the multiple IP addresses.

The manual states they should be separated by commas. Try changing it to

```
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1,192.168.4.70
```

Have you restarted Apache since installing the debugger?

Comment: I have tried that now and yes I always restarted Apache when changing any settings. It still is not working though.

Comment: I have tried several other things.. like I did a ZendDebugger.ini for its own... but still it is not working.